# Metric of the Surface of a Sphere

Tags: homework-and-exercises, differential-geometry, metric-tensor

I am solving for the metric of $S^2$ under stereographic projection. The problem is given as follows,

Consider the surface of a 2-surface embedded in three-dimensional Euclidean space. In a stereographic projection, one assigns coordinates ($\rho$, $\phi$) to each point on the surface of the sphere. The $\phi$-coordinate is the standard azimuthal polar angle. The $\rho$-coordinate of each point is obtained by drawing a straight line in three dimensions from the south pole of the sphere through the point in question and extending the line until it intersects the tangent plane to the north pole of the sphere; the $\rho$-coordinate is then the distance in the tangent plane from the north pole to the intersection point. Show that the line element for the surface of the sphere in these coordinates is

$$ds^2 = \frac{d\rho^2}{(1+\rho^2/a^2)^2} + \frac{\rho^2}{1+\rho^2/a^2} d\phi^2,\tag{1}\label{1}$$

where $a$ is the radius of the sphere. At what point(s) on the sphere are these coordinates degenerate? If instead one works in terms of the Cartesian coordinates $x$ and $y$ in the tangent plane at the north pole, what is the corresponding form of the line element? At what point(s) on the sphere are these new coordinates degenerate?

---

$\textbf{My Solution}$:

[image]

From trigonometry, $\psi = \theta/2$

$\rho = 2a \tan{(\theta/2)}$

$d \rho = a \sec^2{(\theta/2)} d\theta = a (1 + \rho^2/4a^2) d\theta$

$d\theta = d \rho/a (1 + \rho^2/4a^2)$

From the diagram,

$\sin(\theta/2) = \frac{\rho}{\sqrt{\rho^2 + 4a^2}}, \quad \cos(\theta/2) = \frac{2 a}{\sqrt{\rho^2 + 4a^2}}$

$\sin^2(\theta) = 4 \sin^2(\theta/2) \cos^2(\theta/2) = \frac{\rho^2/a^2}{(1+\rho^2/4a^2)^2}$

The metric of the surface on the sphere in spherical coordinates is,

$ds^2 = a^2 d\theta^2 + a^2 \sin^2(\theta) d\phi^2,$

and applying the substitution, we have

$ds^2 = \frac{1}{(1+\rho^2/4a^2)^2} (d\rho^2 + \rho^2 d\phi^2),\tag{2}\label{2}$

which is the metric on the surface under stereographic projection. Also, the coordinates are degenerate at the south pole where $\rho \rightarrow \infty.$

However, the metric I got is not the same as the given. Is it just a typo or am I wrong here?

---

For the second question where I should use Cartesian coordinates in the tangent plane,

$x = a \sin(\theta) \cos(\phi), \quad y = a \sin(\theta) \sin(\phi), \quad x^2 + y^2 = a^2 \sin^2(\theta)$

$dx = a \cos(\theta) \cos(\phi) d\theta - a \sin(\theta) \sin(\phi) d\phi, \quad dy = a \cos(\theta) \sin(\phi) d\theta + a \sin(\theta) \cos(\phi) d\phi$

$dx^2 + dy^2 = a^2 \cos^2(\theta) d\theta^2 + a^2 \sin^2(\theta) d\phi^2$

Taking the differential of $x^2 + y^2 = a^2 \sin^2(\theta)$, we get

$x dx + y dy = a^2 \sin(\theta) \cos(\theta) d\theta,$

and knowing that $a \cos(\theta) = \sqrt{a^2 - x^2 -y^2}$, we have

$d\theta = \frac{x dx + y dy}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}\sqrt{a^2 - x^2 -y^2}}.$

From above we also know that, $a^2 \sin^2(\theta) d\phi^2 = dx^2 + dy^2 - a^2 \cos^2(\theta) d\theta^2,$ so that

$a^2 \sin^2(\theta) d\phi^2 = dx^2 + dy^2 - \frac{(a^2 - x^2 -y^2)(x dx + y dy)^2}{(x^2 + y^2)(a^2 - x^2 -y^2)}.$

When you combine everything, we get

$ds^2 = a^2 d\theta^2 + a^2 \sin^2(\theta) d\phi^2,$

$ds^2 = \Bigg( \frac{a^2 x^2}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}\sqrt{a^2 - x^2 -y^2}} - \frac{x^2}{x^2+y^2} + 1 \Bigg) dx^2 + \Bigg( \frac{a^2 y^2}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}\sqrt{a^2 - x^2 -y^2}} - \frac{y^2}{x^2+y^2} + 1 \Bigg) dy^2 + \Bigg( \frac{2 a^2 x y}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}\sqrt{a^2 - x^2 -y^2}} - \frac{2 xy}{x^2+y^2} \Bigg) dx dy \tag{3}\label{3}$

which is the metric on the surface using Cartesian coordinates in the tangent plane. Also, the coordinates are degenerate at the equator and the north pole where $x^2 + y^2 = a^2$ and $(x,y) = (0,0)$ respectively.

Is my answer correct for the second question?

#Note: This question is taken from the book General Relativity by Hobson, Efstathiou, Lasenby (Exercise 2.4)

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: @Qmechanic . . . but it is a question in a GR book so I think it is also appropriate to be posted here. Should I move it?

Comment: What is the correct metric, can you write it down?

Comment: @Eli That is my question, I am answering a problem as stated above but my answer is different from the one written in the book and I think I am correct but I'm not sure. So I'm asking if the question has a typo.

Comment: You wrote „ However, the metric I got is not the same as the given“  this was my question

Comment: @Eli Yes, the metric written in the book that I should prove is $\eqref{1}$, my answer is $\eqref{2}$, and I want to know what is the correct metric.